# Android Wifi P2P communicate multiple devices

Tags: android

I want to develop a streaming app, where I have to communicate with multiple devices using wifi.

I have tried [P2p](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html), By using this link, i can connect between two devices, but there is no clear documentation for creating group and transferring data between devices.

I even checked some questionnaire related to this topic, but none of them is useful.

Please help me get started in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery/) sample project. I started with this and I can tell you it's straight forward and easy.